# jquery gallery image show

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, gallery

http://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/23060.html
is it possible to do like gallery sample above with jquery?
and where can i grab the jquery plugin!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the images that are half shown util mousing over then you are looking a horizontal accordion slider, an example of this is below.

http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/create_image_menu_with_jquery.html